# Conversion of data type in JAVA

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2005, insert

I'm running my program and I have this error :

```
'[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Disallowed implicit conversion from data type char to data type money, table 'OJT.dbo.Patients', column 'pTotalDue'. Use the CONVERT function to run this query'
```

how can I fix it? can anyone help me?

Here is my codes :

```
private void btnInsertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:OJT_dsn";
        String user = "******";
        String pass = "******";
        String sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Patients" 
                + "(pIDNo,pLName,pFName,pMI,pSex,pStatus,pTelNo,pDocID,pAddr,pStreet,pBarangay,pCity,pProvince,pLnameKIN,pFNameKIN,pMIKIN,pRelationKIN,pTotalDue)"
                + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, txtPatientID.getText());
        pstmt.setString(2, txtpLName.getText());
        pstmt.setString(3, txtpFName.getText());
        pstmt.setString(4, txtpMI.getText());
        pstmt.setString(5, txtSex.getText());
        pstmt.setString(6, txtStatus.getText());
        pstmt.setString(7, txtpTel.getText());
        pstmt.setString(8, txtpDoctor.getText());
        pstmt.setString(9, txtStreetNo.getText());
        pstmt.setString(10, txtStreetName.getText());
        pstmt.setString(11, txtBarangay.getText());
        pstmt.setString(12, txtCity.getText());
        pstmt.setString(13, txtProvince.getText());
        pstmt.setString(14, txtLnameKIN.getText());
        pstmt.setString(15, txtFNameKIN.getText());
        pstmt.setString(16, txtMIKIN.getText());
        pstmt.setString(17, txtRelation.getText());
        pstmt.setString(18, txtTotal.getText());
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Patient Added!");
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is the type of the pTotalDue column? The error says `money` so I guess you can't use `txtTotal.getText()` which is returning a String.

Comment: yes I think so, maybe that's the problem..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `pstmt.setDouble(...);`

```
pstmt.setDouble(18, Double.parseDouble(txtTotal.getText()));
```

Comment: I prefer @Subir Kuma Sao answer: double and money values don't mix because of potential roundoff error.

Answer (score 1):

Its says in the Error,

> Disallowed implicit conversion from data type char to data type money

pTotalDue is not char. You need to set number type value.

Use BigDecimal. Using any primitive will lead to precision problems sooner or later.

Answer (score -1):

You are using JDBC-ODBC Bridge driver for this code, to configure the bridge driver make sure you have properly configured the System DSN

for Windows it is

Control Panel -->Administrative tools-->Data Sources(ODBC)-->System DSN setting for your 
Driver.

or use thin Driver to your code,

for Thin driver please refer the following link

http://www.razorsql.com/articles/oracle_jdbc_connect.html